# Load More With Recycler view Calling Api

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello i have Recycler view that get data from api ,, and all request give me 10 item ,, know i need to implement load more for this recycler and every scroll get another 10 item ,, i tried many times but its not working ,, please help  this is my code

**Adapter**

```
   private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int visibleThreshold = 0;
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

 final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    fragment.getHtmlNewsData("1");
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

and here in **activity**

```
     public void getHtmlNewsData(final String pageNumber) {
        BusinessManager.getNewsDataMethod(pageNumber, new ApiCallResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String StringResponse) {
                String Response = (String) StringResponse;
                try {
                    html = Response.toString();
                    String[] MainSperatedList = html.toString().split("<div class=\"views-field views-field-field-date\">");

                    final List<String> stringsDate = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int counter = 1; counter < MainSperatedList.length; counter++) {
                        String Text = MainSperatedList[counter].toString();
                        String ItemSelected = Jsoup.parse(Text).select("span.date-display-single").text();
                        stringsDate.add(ItemSelected);
                        Log.d("AAAAAAA", ItemSelected);
                    }

 mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                    recyclerViewNews.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    newsReycelerViewAdapter = new NewsReycelerViewAdapter(recyclerViewNews, context, stringsDate, stringsTitle, stringsDetails, stringsImages, new JPANewsFragment());
                    recyclerViewNews.setAdapter(newsReycelerViewAdapter);
                    if (!pageNumber.equals("0"))
                    newsReycelerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

this code its not working for me ,, if anyone have idea please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've achive this by Using these two utils and call recyclerview method addOnScrollListener.**

First create these two utils in java package:

**EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java**

```
package your.pakage.name;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

private int current_page = 1;

private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        // End has been reached

        // Do something
        current_page++;

        onLoadMore(current_page);

        loading = true;
    }
}

   public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
 }
```

**HidingScrollListener.java**

```
package you.package.name;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;


public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

private static final int HIDE_THRESHOLD = 20;

private int mScrolledDistance = 0;
private boolean mControlsVisible = true;


@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
        if(!mControlsVisible) {
            onShow();
            mControlsVisible = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (mScrolledDistance > HIDE_THRESHOLD && mControlsVisible) {
            onHide();
            mControlsVisible = false;
            mScrolledDistance = 0;
        } else if (mScrolledDistance < -HIDE_THRESHOLD && !mControlsVisible) {
            onShow();
            mControlsVisible = true;
            mScrolledDistance = 0;
        }
    }
    if((mControlsVisible && dy>0) || (!mControlsVisible && dy<0)) {
        mScrolledDistance += dy;
    }
}

public abstract void onHide();
public abstract void onShow();
}
```

now after adding these two create your activity.java like this:

**MyActivity.java**

```
package your.package.name;


/**
 * Created by Admin on 9/26/2017.
 */

public class ProductFragment extends Fragment{
private ProductAdapter productAdapter;
private ProductLinearAdapter productLinearAdapter;
public static ArrayList<ProductModel> listProduct;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerviewProducts;
private boolean isGridView = false;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
   // ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageView iv_view;
private LinearLayout ll_sort,ll_filter;
private String checked=null;
private Button view_all;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
String category_id="";
HorizontalDotsProgressBar horizontalDotsProgressBar;
private String rupeeSymbol = "\u20B9";
//CardView cardView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    horizontalDotsProgressBar = (HorizontalDotsProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontalProgress);

    mRecyclerviewProducts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rec_product_view);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_products);
    listProduct = new ArrayList<>();
    productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), listProduct);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
    mRecyclerviewProducts.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerAppliancesVer = new DividerItemDecoration(
            mRecyclerviewProducts.getContext(),
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
    );
    DividerItemDecoration dividerAppliancesHor = new DividerItemDecoration(
            mRecyclerviewProducts.getContext(),
            DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL
    );
    dividerAppliancesVer.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.shape_itemdecoration_vertical));
    dividerAppliancesHor.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.shape_itemdecoration_horizontal));
    mRecyclerviewProducts.addItemDecoration(dividerAppliancesVer);
    mRecyclerviewProducts.addItemDecoration(dividerAppliancesHor);
    mRecyclerviewProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);
    mRecyclerviewProducts.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(gridLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            uiUpdate(category_id,current_page-1,"");
        }
    });
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        category_id = bundle.getString("category_id");
        if (!category_id.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), category_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            uiUpdate(category_id,0,"");
        }
    }


    mRecyclerviewProducts.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            hideViews();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            showViews();
        }
    });

}
private void uiUpdate(final String category_id, final int pagenumber, final String price){

    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(relativeLayout,"Products Loading...",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    snackbar.show();
    //final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    //progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://kibakibi.com/categoryproductapi?access_token=awerttshhjsekjkuy&categoryid=" + category_id+"&page="+pagenumber+"&price="+price,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        Log.d("HomeFragment", "onResponse: " + response);
                        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("products");
                        String message = jsonRootObject.getString("message");
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        snackbar.dismiss();
                        horizontalDotsProgressBar.clearAnimation();
                        horizontalDotsProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String productId = jsonObject.optString("api_product_id");
                                String categoryId = jsonObject.optString("categoryId");
                                String product_Title = jsonObject.optString("productTitle");
                                String previousPrice =  jsonObject.optString("mrp");
                                String actualPrice = jsonObject.optString("expected_payout");
                                String sellerId = jsonObject.optString("seller_id");
                                String description = jsonObject.optString("description");
                                String imageurl = jsonObject.optString("product_images");
                                listProduct.add(new ProductModel(productId,product_Title,imageurl,categoryId,previousPrice,description,actualPrice,sellerId));
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    productAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(pagenumber*1,1);
                    //productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                }
            }
    );
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

private void hideViews() {
   // cardView.animate().translationY(-cardView.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
}
private void showViews() {
   // cardView.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
}
}
```

And not a piece of change in the adapter but i'm gonna add it:

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package your.package.name;



public class ProductAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> list;
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> filterList;
    Context mContext;
    private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
int size = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(MAX_WIDTH * MAX_HEIGHT));
private String rupeeSymbol = "\u20B9";
public ProductAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ProductModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.filterList=list;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_products, parent, false);
    return new ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Typeface montserratregular = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/montserratregular.ttf");
    final ProductModel productModel = filterList.get(position);
    //setting width & height
  /*  DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels / 4;
    int width = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.9);
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));*/
    holder.product_name.setText(productModel.getProduct_title());
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(productModel.getProduct_imageFront())
            .transform(new BitmapTransForms(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT))
            .into(holder.product_image);
    holder.tv_actualPrice.setText(rupeeSymbol+productModel.getExpected_payout());
    holder.tv_previousPrice.setText(rupeeSymbol+productModel.getMrp());
    holder.tv_previousPrice.setPaintFlags(holder.tv_previousPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
   // holder.tv_percentOff.setText(productModel.getMargin());

    // Toast.makeText(mContext,productModel.getProduct_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    holder.tv_actualPrice.setTypeface(montserratregular);
    holder.tv_previousPrice.setTypeface(montserratregular);
    holder.tv_percentOff.setTypeface(montserratregular);
    holder.tv_ratingNumber.setTypeface(montserratregular);
    holder.product_name.setTypeface(montserratregular);
    holder.tv_rating.setTypeface(montserratregular);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return filterList.size();

}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView product_name,tv_actualPrice,tv_previousPrice,tv_percentOff,tv_ratingNumber,tv_rating;
    ImageView product_image;
    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        product_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_productname);
        product_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_products);
        tv_actualPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_actualPrice);
        tv_previousPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_previousPrice);
        tv_ratingNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ratingNumber);
        tv_rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rating);
        tv_percentOff = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_percentOff);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ProductModel productModel = filterList.get(getAdapterPosition());
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SingleProductView.class);
        i.putExtra("image",productModel.getProduct_imageFront());
        i.putExtra("name",productModel.getProduct_title());
        i.putExtra("actualprice",productModel.getExpected_payout());
        i.putExtra("previousPrice",productModel.getMrp());
        i.putExtra("productId",productModel.getApi_product_id());
        Toast.makeText(mContext,productModel.getApi_product_id(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

*It'll work for sure try it an on Youractivity.java pagenumber refer to paging like if your first page getting ten then after scroll it will increment and get the 2nd page value which now have 20 items on your recycler.* If have any problem tell me on comments i'll make them gone.

Comment: thanks for replay but i cannot apply this to my case can you help!

Answer (score 0):

Use **addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener)** from **RecyclerView.java**

```
/**
 * Add a listener that will be notified of any changes in scroll state or position.
 *
 * <p>Components that add a listener should take care to remove it when finished.
 * Other components that take ownership of a view may call {@link #clearOnScrollListeners()}
 * to remove all attached listeners.</p>
 *
 * @param listener listener to set or null to clear
 */
public void addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener)
```

Implementation:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0 && loadingData) {
                visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    //loading flag set to false once data received for the scroll
                    loadingData = false;
                    //Network call using pagination information when scrolled
                    get(pagination, networkRequest);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    clearData();
    //Initial network call to get data from network
    get(pagination, networkRequest);
```

Comment: thanks for replay ,, do you mean add this into activity?

Comment: @MoayedAlayaseh add this where ever you are creating recycler view, just set the respective adapter and add the scroll listener, it wil work like a charm.